# preg_replace all decimals over 3 digits

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to make sure that my date strings have a max of 3 decimals. 
I could use strpos to look for the . and then use substr to get everything to that point + 3, but I was wondering if there is a nicer way to do it with str_replace.

The format is: `'2018-01-01 12:20:23.000000'`, but could also have fewer decimal digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex.
Use the date_create_from and transform the string to a new datetime.

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s\.u', '2018-01-01 12:20:23.123000');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s\.v'); // 2018-01-01 12:20:23.123
```

`u` is microseconds (1-6 digits).
`v` is milliseconds (3 digits).